# Trying to deserialize a complex json file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, data-structures, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json file in c# and print the values of each individual value by using the key, but for the json values that are a list, I'm unable to print the desired values.
Json file:

```
{   
    "prod": {
        "vpc_name": "vpc-us-east-1-it-prod",
        "subnets": {
            "application": [ "subnet-1234", "subnet-1345" ],
            "data":        [ "subnet-64t3", "subnet-f321" ],
            "edge":        [ "subnet-1ff3", "subnet-134g" ]
        }
    },
    "dev": {
        "vpc_name": "vpc-us-east-1-it-dev",
        "subnets": {
            "application": [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-2345tf", "az": "us-east-1a" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-143f1", "az": "us-east-1b" }
            ],
            "data":        [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-134f", "az": "us-east-1b" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-1324", "az": "us-east-1a" }
            ],
            "edge":        [ 
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-123434", "az": "us-east-1a" },
                { "subnet_id": "subnet-123fg", "az": "us-east-1b" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace JsonDeserializer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Users/Stephen.Carvalho/source\repos/JsonDeserializer/JsonDeserializer/vpc_stack.json");
            Rootobject vpcs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonString);
            Console.WriteLine(vpcs.dev.vpc_name);
            Console.WriteLine(vpcs.dev.subnets.application);

        }
    }


    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Prod prod { get; set; }
        public Dev dev { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prod
    {
        public string vpc_name { get; set; }
        public Subnets subnets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subnets
    {
        public string[] application { get; set; }
        public string[] data { get; set; }
        public string[] edge { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dev
    {
        public string vpc_name { get; set; }
        public Subnets1 subnets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subnets1
    {
        public Application[] application { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public Edge[] edge { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; }
        public string az0885b3b66d { get; set; }
        public string az { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; }
        public string az { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge
    {
        public string subnet_id { get; set; }
        public string az { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Hello World!
vpc-us-east-1-it-dev
JsonDeserializer.Application[]
```

I want to print the list of application subnets with prod.subnets but instead of getting the values returned I'm getting JsonDeserializer.Application[] as the output

Comment: The code `Console.WriteLine(vpcs.dev.subnets.application);` is in fact `Console.WriteLine(vpcs.dev.subnets.application.ToString());`, So if you want to see the array content you should iterate elements. Or just serialize the whole object back to JSON and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `vpcs.dev.subnets.application` is an array of `Application`. You can print the array of application subnets by first getting the subnet_ids then converting that array to a string.

**Reason you see `JsonDeserializer.Application[]`** is because your printing the object itself.. when you do that, you get the name of the object type instead of the values inside of it.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", vpcs.dev.subnets.application.Select(x => x.subnet_id)));
```

The `Select` statment goes through each of the application and returns only the subnet_id. Whenever you have an array / list, you can use the select method to get specific items from the list or create new object with this as well.

[Documentation on Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working but what would be great is if you could explain how this works `Select(x => x.subnet_id))` @Jawad

Comment: @stephencarvalho added a link to the documentation on how the Select Statement works.

Comment: Thank you! Understood it well. If you could also please upvote the question so I can increase my reputation on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening since you're trying to print an array in an line, you can try doing something like this:

```
Array.ForEach(vpcs.dev.subnets.application, Console.WriteLine);
```

or parsing it to a list and printing it

```
vpcs.dev.subnets.application.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

or you can also try doing it in a foreach:

```
foreach(var item in vpcs.dev.subnets.application)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: both the methods still return the same thing i.e. JsonDeserializer.Application